# how do I check it's safe to use a class whose parent might not exist?

Tags: php

Suppose I have:

```
class Foo extends MightNotExist {
}
```

where at runtime, MightNotExist might not exist.

I want to do something with Foo if MightNotExist exists, but if it doesn't exist, I want to safely skip Foo.

How can I do that?

I've experimented with catching Error, which doesn't work, and it looks like an error handler won't work either.

Is there anything that can be done short of the following:

1. know the autoload file structure, or ask the autoloader for the file for Foo
2. open the file for Foo as text
3. use a regex / PHP tokenizer to get the parent class name, MightNotExist
4. do class_exists(MightNotExist)

Comment: If you try to extend a class that might not exist, then I'd have said you're doing something wrong

Comment: I was going to post an answer using `if (class_exists("MightNotExist"))`, but then I saw your point #4. Why isn't that acceptable?

Comment: @MarkBaker My code is analysing code in other packages, and some of them have soft dependencies.

Comment: @Barmar sure, but I don't know at runtime what the actual class name of MightNotExist is. I can't use reflection to discover it, as that'll crash.

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't know the class name, how can you define a class that extends it?

Comment: Ok, long detailed explanation: Foo is a service in module Foo, which extends a class in module Bar. Package Bar is a soft dependency, so it's not present. That's ok as far as Foo is concerned, as it's a tagged service which is only ever going to get instantiated if Bar is enabled and collects its tagged services. However! My code is running over all the services defined in the DI container, and when it tries to get the Foo service, it crashes. So what I want to do is guard against that, and know that I should skip Foo.

Comment: [Roave's BetterReflection](https://github.com/Roave/BetterReflection) provides a mechanism to load class files through [composer](https://github.com/composer/composer) without executing the code in the file, so that it can be analysed without any fatal errors; likewise [nikic's PHP_Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) can build the AST from the file without executing the code in the file, for analysing it... I have a mock library that uses nikic's parser to de-finalise classes defined as final so I can extend them, using that approach

Comment: Roave's BetterReflection looks rather good! Unfortunately, I can't use it as the 1.0 version clashes with my own dependencies, and the 2.0 requires PHP 7.1 as a minimum which is too high compared to the minimum requirement of what I'm working with... but I've left myself a TODO to use it in future in my quick and dirty code that hacks the class file with regexes. Care to make your suggestion an answer so I can upvote it, as it certainly solves the problem in general.